# Python - Shuffle an int list in each possible variant

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I'm very new at python and maybe this is a possible duplicate, but I didn't found anything near these topic.

I want to shuffle an int list in each possible variant in python.

Example:

```
a = [2, 5, 8, 9]
```

Expected result:

```
variants = 
[
  [2, 5, 8, 9],
  [2, 5, 9, 8],
  [2, 9, 5, 8],
  [2, 9, 8, 5],
  [2, 8, 9, 5],
  [2, 8, 5, 9],
  [5, 2, 8, 9],
  ...
]
```

Anyone an idea, to do this very fast and efficent?

Thanks for helping me guys.

Comment: Look no further than [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: `from itertools import permutations; list(permutations(a))`

Comment: Thanks to you guys too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

```py
itertools.permutations(a)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.